# Apache rewrite rules not working with variables? Want to disable HTTPS for a certain path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

We serve dozens of websites and don't want to do vhost specific re-write rules. Basically, I need all /info/ pages to never be served via HTTPS.

Currently we have this:

```
RewriteRule ^/info/([A-Za-z_.0-9-]*) /info.jsp?LinkName=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
```

I thought I could change the rewrite rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^/info/([A-Za-z_.0-9-]*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/info.jsp?LinkName=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/info/([A-Za-z_.0-9-]*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/info.jsp?LinkName=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/info/([A-Za-z_.0-9-]*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/info.jsp?LinkName=$1 [PT,QSA,L,R=301]
```

etc...

But no matter what I do, when making any re-write rule changes involving a variable, I 404 when hitting these info pages:

> "Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not
>   understand."

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does that prevent /info/ pages from getting served via HTTPS?

Comment: @Jon Lin .. well, right, and that's what brings me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule that you already have for rewriting to info.jsp is fine. But you need to add a couple of rules **before** it.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?info/ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use the `passthrough` (`PT`) flag if you're rewriting to a fully qualified URL.  This would have to be handled as a client redirect.  If you replace `PT` with `R` (or just remove the `PT` flag where you already have the `R` flag) it should work.

Comment: Caveat: I have not actually tested this.